Tensorflow Keras saved model does not contain correct input names
We are using tensorflow 2.12 for training a prediction model and serving via Tensorflow-Serving REST API for prediction. The training works fine and we have a ServingModel as follows
    inp = {
        "request_features": tf.keras.Input(
            name="request_features,
            shape=(10,),
            dtype=tf.float32,
        ),
        "content_id": tf.keras.Input(
            name="content_id", shape=(), dtype=tf.string
        ),
        "product_sku": tf.keras.Input(
            name="product_sku",
            shape=(None,),
            dtype=tf.string,
            ragged=True,
        ),
        "country_id": tf.keras.Input(
            shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name="country_id"
        ),
        "sales_channel": tf.keras.Input(
            shape=(), dtype=tf.int64, name="sales_channel"
        ),
    }

    serving_core_layer = ServingLayer(
        model,
        name="serving_layer",
    )
    out = serving_core_layer(inp)
    tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=out)

where ServingLayer is defined generally
class ServingLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  # We have some complex handling on the input and processing
  # which I could not simply abstract here

After the model is trained and saved. I found out the output metadata lost the input names, such as request_features, content_id, instead, the input layer names become args_0, args_0_1, etc. Also, there is a warning when the model was saved
WARNING:absl:Function `_wrapped_model` contains input name(s) args_0 with unsupported characters which will be renamed to args_0_3 in the SavedModel

and the model output metadata is like
signature_def['serving_default']:
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following input(s):
    inputs['args_0'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0:0
    inputs['args_0_1'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0_1:0
    inputs['args_0_2'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0_2:0
    inputs['args_0_3'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 10)
        name: serving_default_args_0_3:0
    inputs['args_0_4'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_INT64
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0_4:0
    inputs['args_0_5'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_STRING
        shape: (-1)
        name: serving_default_args_0_5:0
  The given SavedModel SignatureDef contains the following output(s):
    outputs['serving_layer'] tensor_info:
        dtype: DT_FLOAT
        shape: (-1, 1)
        name: StatefulPartitionedCall:0
  Method name is: tensorflow/serving/predict 

So, seems we have 5 InputLayers, but now there are 6 Inputs in metadata including args_0, and we lost the Input real names, so I could not make correct request body for calling REST API for prediction.
So, could anyone help what might cause this problem and how to fix it? Thanks!

After some debugging, if I comment out ragged=True for product_sku InputLayer, the model metadata can be saved correctly with correct input names.
